# Pygame: Collision of two images

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm working on my school project for which im designing a 2D game.

I have 3 images, one is the player and the other 2 are instances (coffee and computer). What i want to do is, when the player image collides with one of the 2 instances i want the program to print something.

I'm unsure if image collision is possible. But i know rect collision is possible. However, after several failed attempts, i can't manage to make my images rects. Somebody please help me. Here is my source code:

```
import pygame
import os

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
blue=(0,0,255)


class Player(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
        self.image2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.coffee=pygame.image.load("coffee.png")
        self.computer=pygame.image.load("computer.png")
        self.flipped = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0


    def handle_keys(self):
        """ Movement keys """
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
            self.y += dist 
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: 
            self.y -= dist 
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
            self.x += dist
            self.flipped = False
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist
            self.flipped = True

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.flipped:
            image = self.image2
        else:
            im = self.image            
        for x in range(0, 810, 10):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [x, 0, 10, 10])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [x, 610, 10, 10])

        for x in range(0, 610, 10):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [0, x, 10, 10])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [810, x, 10, 10])

        surface.blit(self.coffee, (725,500))
        surface.blit(self.computer,(15,500))
        surface.blit(im, (self.x, self.y))



pygame.init()



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))#creates the screen

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()      # quit the screen
            running = False

    player.handle_keys()       # movement keys
    screen.fill((255,255,255)) # fill the screen with white




    player.draw(screen)        # draw the player to the screen
    pygame.display.update()    # update the screen

    clock.tick(60)             # Limits Frames Per Second to 60 or less
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep image size and position.

Image (or rather `pygame.Surface()`) has function `get_rect()` which returns `pygame.Rect()` with image size (and position).

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Now you can set start position ie. `(0, 0)`

```
self.rect.x = 0
self.rect.y = 0

# or 

self.rect.topleft = (0, 0)

# or

self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=0, y=0)
```

(`Rect` use left top corner as (x,y)).

Use it to change position

```
self.rect.x += dist
```

and to draw image

```
surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

and then you can test collision

```
if self.rect.colliderect(self.rect_coffe):
```

---

BTW: and now `class Player` looks almost like [pygame.sprite.Sprite](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) :)

Comment: Ok, i incorporated the changes, i made the player a rect and also the coffee. i placed the collision test before the while loop and i put in

if self.rect.colliderect(self.rect_coffe):
     print "no"

As soon as i start the program it prints "no".

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: after `key handle` and before `draw`.

Comment: did you set coffe position in `rect_coffe` ? as default rect use (x=0, y=0). you can always `print(self.rect, self.rect_coffe)` to see positions.

Comment: So when i blit the coffee i put this is

surface.blit(self.coffee,self.coffee_rect,[725,500])

But i get an invalid argument style. What should i correct?

Comment: only `surface.blit(self.coffee, self.coffee_rect)` but at the beginnig you have to set `self.coffee_rect.topleft = [725,500]`